# Combining 2 redux stores from 2 different projects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

First of all, I'm a beginner in React & Redux.

I'm trying to get components from one project to another. I made one project a npm package, so i can import directly from this project. The problem is that I'm using a store in my main project and my npm package uses a store as well. This results in states being undefined because I only give one store with the provider.

this is the index.js from my main project, I know you can't have 2 Providers, but I wanted to point out that I'm searching to have the functionality of both stores:

```
import { guiReducer, intlInitialState } from 'second-project';
const secondStore = createStore(guiReducer, intlInitialState);
const store = configureStore();

render(
<Provider store={store}>
 <Provider store={secondStore}
  <Router>
   <App />
  </Router>
 </Provider>
</Provider>
```

This is the configureStore.js:

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

function configureStoreProd(initialState){
 return createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
}

const configureStore =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? configureStoreProd : configureStoreDev;


export default configureStore;
```

rootReducer is a combined reducer from the main project and guiReducer is a combined reducer from the second project.
Sample code for rootReducer (similar for guiReducer):

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
 loggedIn,
 courses,
 lessons,
 organisation,
});

const rootReducer = (state,action) => {
 if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
   state = initialState;
 }
 return appReducer(state,action);
};

export default rootReducer;
```

I also tried to combine both root/gui-reducers and making a new store like this (configureStore.js) :

```
function configureCombinedStoreProd(initialState){
 return createStore(
   combineReducers({
    rootReducer,
    guiReducer,
   }), initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk)
 );
}

const configureCombinedStore = 
 process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? configureCombinedStoreProd : 
   configureCombinedStoreDev; 

export {configureCombinedStore as configureCombinedStore };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have currently solved this by wrapping the components in App.js with a
`<Provider store={store}>`
from the second project while in index.js "App" is wrapped with the provider from the main project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to avoid saving another store in the npm package. Instead, wrap only the components you need inside the npm package, make them accept properties different than "store", and copy the old project's reducers inside your "reducers" folder. Instead, if you use the "[duck pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)", you may want to save the old reducers in the npm package as well (only the reducers, not the store!) and import them in your store when you call something like `combineReducers` inside your new store.js file.

Comment: Copying the old project's reducers isn't an option as it doesn't provide a long term solution. The published npm package is an open source project, I want a solution where it's possible to be able to pull from that repository and do (minor) changes and publish the package again.